# Is it possible to call a function without assigning a return type

Tags: c#

In vba, i am able to use 'call myfunction()' without assigning a return type to a variable (myvar = myfunction). is this possible in c#? I am trying to use -

```
HTMLDOCUMENT.getElementById("ElementID").click
```

but its giving me an error about it cant be used as a statement.

Comment: Q: Is it possible to call a function without assigning a return type?  A: Sure. In just about every language I know of.  PROBLEM: [HtmlDocument.GetElementById()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid?view=netframework-4.8) is a C#/VB.Net function that you're calling incorrectly: `HtmlDocument.GetElementById(String)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't about using or having a return-type - it's about syntax: C# requires all function calls and method calls to use parenthesis, whereas VB6/VBA/VBS only requires parenthesis for `Function` calls and actually proscribes them for `Sub` functions.

Change your code to this, note the added `();`.

```
HTMLDOCUMENT.getElementById("ElementID").click();
```

In VB6, VBA, VBScript and VB.NET a function (or method) that doesn't return a value is called a `Sub` - and its call-sites don't use parenthesis (except in VB.NET).

In C-style languages (including C, C++, Java, C#, Swift, TypeScript), if a function (or method) doesn't return something then its declared the same way as a function that does return a value, except its return-type is replaced with `void` (and all call-sites must use parenthesis).

```
' VBA/VB6-style function definitions:

Function GetAnInteger() As Integer

    GetAnInteger = 123

End Function

Sub ReturnNothing()


End Sub
```

```
' Call-site examples:

Dim number As Integer
number = GetAnInteger()    ' <-- Uses parenthesis.

ReturnNothing              ' <-- No parenthesis.
```

```
// C-style / C# function definition:

int GetAnInteger() {
    return 123;
}

void ReturnNothing() {

}
```

```
// Call-site examples:

int number = GetAnInteger();    // <-- Uses parenthesis.

ReturnNothing();                // <-- Also uses parenthesis.
```

Comment: You are the man. i thought i had to use a keyword or something. c# syntax is very unforgiving.

Comment: @Padawan I appreciate C# (and C-style in general) has a steep learning curve for someone coming from a VB background (myself included!) - but eventually you'll begin to *prefer* the terseness of C#'s syntax and its stricter rules because it allows you to be more expressive by writing less code. Additionally, VBA/VB6's "forgiving" nature actually makes programming _harder_ (e.g. because variables are all case-insensitive, or because its breaking [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) ).

Comment: `Eventually you'll begin to prefer the terseness of C#'s syntax and its stricter rules`.  I agree completely!  Not necessarily "less code" (I *HATE* it when people whine about a few extra keystrokes), but certainly *BETTER* code (fewer inadvertent bugs).

Comment: my first lang was c++, but i been doing vba for the last 10 +years for work. it really has destroyed me.

Comment: I hope you've been using `Option Explicit` for most of that decade ;)

Comment: @Padawan C++ has changed **a lot** in the past 10 years btw thanks to C++11 and everything since then. Templates are even more powerful and C++ is starting to embrace functional programming - which means the learning curve for VB people is only going to get even more steeper (e.g. try explaining C++ lambda captures (let alone SFINAE) to a person who has only ever written VB).